# interval 6 month but with user added dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched and searched for an answer to this, but the only examples I come across are for ones using the preset `date('Y-m-d')` command.

I have three fields in my database - month, day, year. These fields have values entered into them by a person, not the computer. Now, how do I figure out how to NOT show the entries that are less than 6 months old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert and cast your individual columns into a datetime, then compare it to today ... something like this??

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   cast(CONCAT(year, '-', month, '-', day) as datetime) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

Comment: Having checked into all the other examples given, this one seemed to make the most sense to me and it worked. Kind of. Only problem is that it was showing ONLY the dates that were less than six months. Switching the '>' to a '<' showed me that dates older than six months - which is what i wanted. Now, I have a problem with it not showing any fields where the year, month, day are blank. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `date` function ... just combine it with the `mktime` function.

```
// DATE IN IDF
// WILL RETURN 2013-08-12
$date_less_6_months = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 6, date("d"), date("Y")));

// DATE BROKEN APART
$year_less_6_months = date("Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 6, date("d"), date("Y")));
$month_less_6_months = date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 6, date("d"), date("Y")));
$date_less_6_months = date("d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 6, date("d"), date("Y")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_six_months_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-6 months"));
```

now you can compare those with your database values.
Check [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for all date formats.

so maybe you want to check year, month and day separated.
use:

```
$day = date("d", strtotime($date_six_months_ago));
$month = date("m", strtotime($date_six_months_ago));
$year= date("Y", strtotime($date_six_months_ago));
```

Maybe you will need to format the database value, use the following SQL:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say following are from your database

```
$d = '02';
$m = '06';
$y = '2013';
```

Now lest see the difference from now

```
$d1 = new DateTime($y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d);
$d2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));

$interval = $d2->diff($d1);

$months = $interval->format('%m months');
```

Now $months will contain the difference in months

You can check here  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php